# JavaFX8 - Remove highlighting of selected row

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

When I click on a row within a `TableView` the row will be highlighted blue. How is it possible to disable this feature?
I've already tried to set the background to white, but the problem is that the row-color isn't white in every row.
Does anybody know what to do?

best regards

EDIT:

In the image below you see the blue color of the second row. This highlighting should be removed.

[image]

Comment: what _do_ you want to achieve? Removing the visible clue for selection doesn't sound user-friendly

Comment: updated the question. hope this helps to understand my question. the point is that I have a TableView with some controls in the cells. so highlighting a row by clicking on them looks terrible and is distracting the user.

Comment: In addition to styling there's `TableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);` That makes just one cell highlighted.

Comment: The point is that I want the program not to highlight anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this (I agree with @kleopatra in the comments that it would make life difficult for the user) you can revert the colors for selected rows with an external css file:

```
.table-row-cell:filled:selected {
  -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background ;
  -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0 ;
  -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-color, 5%);
}
.table-row-cell:odd:filled:selected {
  -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt ;
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but there are still borders around every cell in the marked row. `-fx-border-width: 0;` and `-fx-border-color: transparent;` didn't help. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Updated. Sometimes it's useful to look at how styles are defined in the [default stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)

Comment: I was trying to find an "elegant" way to get this to work; but you're right, just changing the `-fx-selection-bar` leaves a subtle change. I think the only way is to revert everything that is set for selected cells. This seems to work for me: I can't tell at all which row is selected...