# Disable row selection in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a read-only TableView in JavaFX 8, and I don't want' the users to select rows.
They should still be able to sort the columns and scroll, just not to select any rows.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: technically, you could null the selectionModel - might disable navigation, though (can't try right now). Also, copy would not be possible. Curious: why do you  want to detoriate user experience?

Comment: @kleopatra Setting the SelectionModel to null will throw exceptions when the user sorts the columns.

Comment: good to know, thanks for the info :-) Sounds like a bug to me (null selectionModel is a valid value), so filed an issue: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39624

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a while I found how to solve it so posting it here for future users.
The solution is based on this answer:
[JavaFX8 - Remove highlighting of selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013898/javafx8-remove-highlighting-of-selected-row)

After adding the following lines to your css, selected lines will look exactly as unselected lines, achieving the same effect I wanted in the same place:

```
.table-row-cell:filled:selected { 
  -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background ;
  -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0 ;
  -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-color, 5%);
}
.table-row-cell:odd:filled:selected {
  -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt ;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can disable selection, by setting `selectionModel` to `null`.

```
table.setSelectionModel(null);
```

Comment: Does this not break sorting in the table aswell?

Comment: It throws for me with ListView with JavaFX 8, any ways to disable selection?

Comment: TableView.java, method: sort(), row 1531, calls getSelectionModel().startAtomic(); this answer does lead to a nullpointerexception

Comment: Throws a lot of internal exceptions on click

Answer (score 6):

I've just hit this issue myself. I think the best way to solve it is to provide a null implementation of TableViewSelectionModel.

Then you can simply say `tableView.setSelectionModel(new NullTableViewSelectionModel(tableView));`

A sample null implementation is below...

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class NullTableViewSelectionModel extends TableView.TableViewSelectionModel {

    public NullTableViewSelectionModel(TableView tableView) {
        super(tableView);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TablePosition> getSelectedCells() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectRightCell() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectAboveCell() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectBelowCell() {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int i, TableColumn tableColumn) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int i, TableColumn tableColumn) {

    }

    @Override
    public void select(int i, TableColumn tableColumn) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int i, TableColumn tableColumn) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList getSelectedItems() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectIndices(int i, int... ints) {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void select(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void select(Object o) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectPrevious() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectNext() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectFirst() {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectLast() {

    }
}
```

Comment: `isEmpty()` should return true IMHO.

Comment: I like this approach, however I am still seeing a (focus?) rectangle when I click in the `TableView`.

Answer (score 5):

I found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2522099?start=0&tstart=0) another solution for the same problem but for a ListView. The pattern is: listen the selection change event, and then clear the selection. It works also for the TableView.
Code example:

```
    _tableView.getSelectionModel()
               .selectedIndexProperty()
               .addListener((observable, oldvalue, newValue) -> {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            _tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        });

    });
```